# Similarity of LDA & Word2vec to cluster words

Tags: nlp, cluster-analysis, word2vec, doc2vec

recently I am working on a project of text mining. My goal is to cluster comments based on their topics(contents).

I tried a model myself based on:https://www.kaggle.com/liananapalkova/simply-about-word2vec. It seems that creating word-vectors can definitely take me to my goal, I was thinking to use doc2vec and create vectors that represent each of the comments and perform k-means and other unsupervised learning clustering techniques(i.e. treat it just as numeric).

Then I look something up about LDA, I found that use a lot of sub-topics to describe a document(the comment in my case) also makes sense, eventually, I will let the LDA assign some topics to each of my comments.

My question is: It seems word2vec/doc2vec is using some tokens to represent the word, while LDA uses some topics to represent those documents, they sound really similar! Can I combine the technique of word2vec and LDA together, to get my clusters of comments, at the same assign each cluster some topics?

How does it work? I am looking on Kaggle but cannot find some similar projects...

Comment: Some sample Python codes will be highly appreciated! I find it hard to get insights from research papers......

Comment: Just because they are similar does not mean they can be easily combined nor that it works well. A car and a motorcycle are pretty similar, the combination trike isn't too popular.